# create a compressed tar archive from files extracted from another tar archive

Tags: bash, pipe, tar

I'm trying to do what I specified in the object. I have a tar.gz archive (i.e. **archive.tar.gz**) and I want to:

1. extract only some file (e.g. ***.csv**) contained in a specific folder of the archive (e.g. **CSV_DIR**).
2. create a new tar.gz archive containing only files extracted in the previous step.

I can do that easily creating a temporary subdirectory with this bash instructions:

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz --xform='s#^.+/##x' --wildcards -C /path/to/subdir "**/CSV_DIR/*csv"
tar -czf csvarchive.tar.gz -C /path/to/dir .
```

My question is, how can I do that piping the output of the first instruction to the second one?

I tried something like:

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz --xform='s#^.+/##x' --wildcards "**/CSV_DIR/*csv" | tar -czf csvarchive.tar.gz -T -
```

But the archive created is empty.

Some suggestions?